# Tensorflow Lite inference memory allocation

Tags: tensorflow, memory, tensorflow-lite

Usually during the neural network inference, especially for forward NN, after the execution at one layer finishes, one can safely discard the result of the previous layer, since it won't be used any more (except for those with shortcut connections.). So memory can be saved during the inference. My question is whether TFlite is doing this at this moment. By looking at their C++ code, it seems that they now allocate all the tensors before hand (input, output and intermediate tensors). But I might be wrong. Can anyone confirm this?

Thank you!